# Adobe Flex and ADA Compliance

Tags: apache-flex, accessibility, wcag

Is it possible to make Flex applications as ADA Compliance ?

Comment: I've done a lot of flex/actionscript accessibility programming and while it's not as straightforward as ARIA and HTML, you **can** make flex applications accessible.  That's a simple answer to your simple question, "yes".  After reading the links posted by others, then if you have a specific flex question, you can post that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.  [Have you read the documentation on Flex and Accessibility?](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/).

If you're dong advanced things w/ custom components, you may have to create your own accessible versions, but most of the built in components to the Flex Framework should be accessible.

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex+Accessibiolity&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=lKb&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&&sa=X&ei=G_QZTf9lhfqXB9nW1ewC&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=Flex+Accessibility&spell=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec) on the topic brings up other relevant links.